# Управление логами Апача

Tags: логирование, linux

В папке апача лежат логи, которые нумеруются, обновляются и архивируются по каким-то своим правилам. Вопрос, как узнать, где эти правила определяются и настраиваются, и как их менять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот процесс (нумерации, обновления, архивации и тд.) называют ротацией логов. За это отвечает утилита `logrotate`

```
man logrotate
```

На Ubuntu настройки лежат в файле `/etc/logrotate.conf` (в других системах может быть по другому).